# How to prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3}$ is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have to prove that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3} $$ is not Lebesgue integrable.
I have tried doing this:
(USING THIS DEFINITION: $f  \text{ (measurable function) Lebesgue integrable} \Leftrightarrow  \int_{(0,+\infty)}|f| d\mu<\infty$)
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)}|f| d\mu=\int_{(0,+\infty)}\left|\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3}\right| d\mu=\int_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3} d\mu + \int_{(1,+\infty)}\frac{-1}{x^2ln(x)^3} d\mu$$
Then,  $$\int_{(0,1)}\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3} d\mu=?=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2ln(x)^3} dx\geq \int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2} dx=+\infty $$
But, as we can see, I have proved that the functions Riemann's improper integral is divergent. Can I say that its Lebesgue integral is divergent too? I don't think so.

Apart from that, I don't know how to prove that $f$ is measurable. I've tried using that it is continuous, but it isn't when $x=1$.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann integral of  a continuous function on close interval coincides with its Lebesgue integral.

$\int_a^{1-a} |f(x)| dx$ is a Riemann  integral for each $a \in (0,\frac 1  2)$. And $\int_a^{1-a} |f(x)| dx \to \infty$ as  $a$ decreases to $0$ since $|ln x| \leq |\ln a|$ on $(a,1-a)$ and $\int_a^{1-a} \frac  1 {x^{2}}dx\to \infty$ by direct calculation of the integral.  Since $\int_0^{1} |f(x)| dx \geq \int_a^{1-a} |f(x)| dx$ we  are done.

Hint for measurability: $\{x \neq 1: f(x) <a\}=\{x \in (0,1) \cup (1,\infty): \frac 1 {x (\ln x)^{3}} <a\} $ which is an open set by continuity. The function is not defined at $x=1$. If you define it  say as $0$ at this point what happens to $\{x: f(x) <a\}$?

Comment: I don't really understand what you've done with the integral... I understand the first line, but  $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{ln(x)^3x^2} dx $ is an improper integral, isn't it? If so, I wouldn't be able to say that Lebesgue integral is dibergent, right?

Comment: @a12456 I have edited my answer to avoid improper integrals.

Comment: But, when you bound the integral (which is improper), what you get is that it is, in fact, divergent... That's what I don't actually see...

Comment: I hope the answer is clear now. The proof avoids improper integrals. That is the basic idea. @a12456